# This cannot be referenced in a static context

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I want to call this method but I get the following error : This cannot be referenced in a static context

**My class**

```
public with sharing class CTRL_CoproGestionSyndic {

     public list<gnp__Element_immobilier__c> elementsImmo;
     public list<gnp__Cle_de_repartition__c> clesRepartition;

     @AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
     public static list<gnp__Element_immobilier__c> getElementImmo(Id coproId){
          //code 
          ...
          this.elementsImmo = elementImmo;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your static method `getElementImmo` is trying to access the `this` instance in order to store a given parameter value into the instance variable `elementsImmo`. It cannot.

The difference between static (sometimes also called "class") and non-static (sometimes also called "instance") method is that one is that the static one is called on the class, while an instance method is called on an instance of the class.

A static method only has access to its parameters and any static variables in the class, while an instance method has access to all this AND the instance variable (being a property or variable on the class). However, the instance method can only be called on an instance of the class.

Take this example. Let's define a class called Person:

```
public class Person {
  static Double averageAge = 0;
  static Integer numberOfPersons = 0;

  Integer age;

  public static Integer getAverageAge() {
    return averageAge;
  }

  public Person(Integer age) {
    this.age = age; // explicit to distinguish instance attribute and parameter

    averageAge = ((averageAge * numberOfPersons) + age) / (numberOfPersons + 1); // the static value
    numberOfPersons++; // the static value
  }

  public Integer getAge() {
    return age; // implicitly this.age
  }
}
```

The static method `getAverageAge` returns a static variable called `averageAge` without the need for a Person instance:

```
Integer average = Person.getAverageAge();

System.debug(average);
```

However, to create a Person with an age and then to get that age I must have an instance:

```
Person me = new Person(35); // create a new instance
Person you = new Person(15);

Integer myAge = me.getAge(); // access the instance method to get the instance variable
Integer average = Person.getAverageAge();

System.debug(myAge);
System.debug(average);
```

See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm) for more on static and instance methods and variables.

For you, you likely need to make the `elementsImmo` List static so it is accessible from the Aura Enabled method - such methods are mandated as static to be called from lightning (aura or web) components.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods are very light weight. It does not create a **instance** of the class from where it is getting called.
In you code snippet because `This` keyword represents the current **instance** of a class and as static methods **does not** create any **instance** of a class. Thus you cannot use `this` keyword from static methods.

You need to keep a static variable instead of non-static variables.

More info on static can be found in [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm)

Comment: This does not really explain the difference between static and instance variables very well. I recommend at the very least adding a reference to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm).

Comment: @PhilW Yeah actually, i wrote reference of class instead of instance of class, I have added more description now.